# Extra white space in between frame and table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I want to make a drawing. I want a titleblock in the bottom right corner of the page. however it seems like there's an extra column on the right side of the table that gives me some unwanted result.

my code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[a3paper, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw (current page.center)  
            ++(-20,14) coordinate (NW) % using 40x28cm
        --  ++(40,0) coordinate (NE)
        --  ++(0,-28) coordinate (SE)
        --  ++(-40,0) coordinate (SW)
        --  cycle;
    % numbered layout
    \foreach \x [count=\i from 1] in {0,5,...,35}
        \draw (NW) ++(\x,0) rectangle ++(5,-0.7) ++(-2.5, 0.35) node[]{\i};
    % table SE 
    \node [draw, anchor=south east, align=center, font=\large, inner sep=0pt] 
        at (SE) 
        {
            \begin{tabular}{|llll|}
                \hline
                \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{Titel}}                                                                             \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Auteur}}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Auteur}     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{...} & ... \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Datum}}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\today}           & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{...} & ... \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{...}               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{...}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{...} & ... \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
%electrical schematic

            
\end{document}
```

image with the problem:

[image: seems to be an extra white space in between table and the frame of the page]

Comment: You have a space in the node after the table, so add a `%`:  `\end{tabular}% <--- `